# C++ Function type and params including their type as arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, typedef

In my class I have a function named `CallFn()` which type needs to be assigned from arguments, as well as undefined number of params including their type. I then need to call another function using the data provided in the params + the function address that's stored in the class variable. What would be the best practice to do so and how can I achieve it?

Let's take this is as a pseudo-example:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    DWORD dwAddress = 0x12345;

    // Function type A = void in the current example
    // However there could be more or less arguments
    A CallFn( FUNC_TYPE A, void* B, unsigned int C, bool D )
    {
        // Call this function
    }
};
```

And then call it like this:

```
MyClass->CallFn(void, void* B, unsigned int C, bool D);
// or
MyClass->CallFn(bool, int B, DWORD C, char* D);
```

As before I would just have a typedef and cast it using the address manually:

```
typedef void( __thiscall *CallFn )( void*, unsigned int, bool );

CallFn _CallFn;

_CallFn = ( CallFn ) ( DWORD ) 0x12345;
```

Few ideas come to mind using modern c++ standards, such as alias declaration with `using` and templates, but I'm too much of a beginner to actually write ready-to use code, even after a lot of searching, so I decided to post and see whether there might be an alternative or perhaps even better way to achieve, what I want to do and possibly even improve the idea further.

Comment: Use `std::function` rather than a raw function pointer.

Comment: Have a look into templates. They provide the mechanism to write a function that works on arbitrary types (as long as they support what the function is doing with them).

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, `std::function` combined with templates actually seems like a decent solution, however is it possible to make std::function itself a function and return the defined call to make it cleaner? Or what would be the best way to implement this? Having a simple function with params that creates a new `std::function` and then calls it seems kind-of awkward.

Comment: Apparently std::function is not supported on VS 2015 RTM yet, any alternative @πάνταῥεῖ ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a function [template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template%20Templates) and the [auto](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) specifier. Here's a quick example.

```
#include <iostream>

class Example
{
    public:
    template<typename A>
    auto test(A x) -> decltype(x)
    {
        return x;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Example obj;
    /* The function below is of type int and its argument is int */
    std::cout << obj.test(5) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know if you can make it work with `void`, but maybe you could consider overloading in that case.

Comment: Thank you, would you mind elaborating how I would override that specific function and add arguments with their type as arguments?